# How do Antishock Bodies / Cuchemann Carrots delay shock-induced flow separation?

Tags: aerodynamics

[image]

[image]

There are several online resources that describe these aerodynamic devices as either "Antishock Bodies" or "Kuchemann Carrots" and that they are used to produce some combination of the following effects:

1. Delay shock-induced flow  separation
2. Contribute to the Area-Rule concept
3. Both of the above (source-dependent)

I cannot find any reading about how these devices perform the task of delaying shock induced flow separation. I am interested in how exactly these bodies interact with the combination of supersonic and subsonic flow across the chord line of a transonic wing in order to delay shock-induced flow separation to some higher Mach number than would be possible without them installed.